# Ektron Site search not returning results

Tags: search, ektron

Using Ektron 9.0 SP2 and I installed Microsoft Search Server 2010 as a part of the Ektron Search Server. We currently have our site configured to use the WebSearch plugin, but as of late, it is not returning any results and only the Suggested Results we have setup in the Workarea. Code as follows:

```
<CMS:WebSearch ID="WebSearch1" runat="server" BackColor="White">
```

I should add that the Sharepoint Crawler seems to be doing its job and is crawling the site every day as scheduled right after the AppPool recycles. However, searching for anything that is not in a set of Synonyms for the search yields "No Results".

In a completely NEW page, I copied the search page and put the following:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Ektron.Cms.Framework.UI.Controls"
    Namespace="Ektron.Cms.Framework.UI.controls"
    TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

And later down the page:

```
<cc1:SiteSearchInputView ID="searchinput" runat="server"
     ControllerID="searchcontroller" />
<cc1:SiteSearchController ID="searchcontroller" runat="server" />
<cc1:SiteSearchResultsView ID="searchresults" runat="server"
     ControllerID="searchcontroller" />
```

I figured that using the new controls would somehow unlock new functionality and be able to display the results of my searches.

I was wrong.

What is going on here?

Every search returns "No Results" unless is is one of the Suggested Results.

EDIT:  After communicating with Ektron Support, they determined that the installation of Microsoft Search Server Express had been corrupted and needed to be reinstalled. Seems a shame that something as simple as installing a Service Pack would corrupt core functionality. I will EDIT this post again with an update if reinstalling Search Server resolved the issue.

Comment: Did the search work previously? If not I would make sure that all the search settings in web.config are pointing at the correct service, etc.

Comment: Does the basic search within the Workarea work? Can you search within the MSS Sharepoint UI? Did you run the search connection utility successfully?

Comment: Yes, the search worked previously. We installed SP2 on our system and that was what seems to have broken the search. I will check the web.config again to see.

The basic search within the Workarea doesn't work either. Only the advanced search does, so I know it can connect to my databases. I have no idea if I can search from within Sharepoint, I've never tried. As @MaxPRafferty mentioned, I may need to check my web.config again.

Comment: Advanced search goes directly against the DB - so it would work if you had no search connected at all - which is why I asked about the basic search, specifically. Sounds like you may need to reregister your site with the search server.